# How can I set a timeout for urllib3 request?

Tags: python, urllib3

How can I get urllib3 to try to reach a site for 10 seconds and return an error or data if it can't?

```py
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

page = http.request('get', link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [**`Timeout configuration`** <sup>[urllib3-docs]</sup>](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Timeout)
you can set a timeout for your request when you're using `urllib3` in all the below ways:

> Timeouts can be defined as a default for a pool:
>
> ```py
> timeout = Timeout(connect=2.0, read=7.0)
> http = PoolManager(timeout=timeout)
> response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
> ```
>
> Or per-request (which overrides the default for the pool):
>
> ```py
> response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/', >timeout=Timeout(10))
> ```
>
> Timeouts can be disabled by setting all the parameters to None:
>
> ```py
> no_timeout = Timeout(connect=None, read=None)
> response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/, >timeout=no_timeout)
> ```

And I think your solution is sth like below the code snippet:

```py
from urllib3 import Timeout, Poolmanager

timeout = Timeout(connect=10.0, read=None)
http = PoolManager(timeout=timeout)
response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I forgot to write in the question I'm using PoolManager()

Answer (score 2):

From the docs

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Timeout

```py
from urllib3 import Timeout, Poolmanager
```

```py
timeout = Timeout(connect=2.0, read=7.0)
http = PoolManager(timeout=timeout)
response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
```